# how to animate a div layer on top of another div layer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to immitate effect of this [site](http://www.mckinsey.com/) .  They have two layers `layer-top` and `layer-base`.  The base layer animates on top of the `top` layer in a very nice way.  I tried looking at the source but it is really complex.

I am trying to do the same effect on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/izexu3/2

can someone help me in getting me started with an effect like this?

I see that there are [pageSlide plugins](http://derekperez.com/jquery-pageslide/demo/) for jQuery however, they do not have the same effect as what I want.  In the plugins, the div on left side is moved further to the right rather than sliding a div on top of another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/4mPbV/

html:

```
<div id="slide-pane">
    <button id="toggle-button">←</button>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#toggle-button").data("open", false);

$("#toggle-button").click(function() {
    // slide to the right
    if ($(this).data("open") == false) {
        $("#slide-pane").animate({
            width: '+=400'
        }, function(){ $("#toggle-button").text("→"); });
        $(this).data("open", true);
    }
    // slide to the left
    else {
        $("#slide-pane").animate({
            width: '-=400'
        }, function(){ $("#toggle-button").text("←"); });
        $(this).data("open", false);
    }
});
```

css:

```
#slide-pane {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #33339F;
}
```

Comment: Be careful, i get an Clickjacking alert from NoScript in Firefox! Something is going wrong there...

Answer (score 1):

you can simply animate one layer to get this effect.

Example here: http://jsbin.com/okaxa4